# How difficult/time consuming is to build a vertical editor?

Tags: javascript, editor

this editor is horizontal http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/simple.php
and I seem to find only horizonal editors, has anyone came across a vertical editor? any examples? how long would it take to build?

I mean the toolbar is horizontal and I want to use a vertical one instead? (I don't mean for languages)
I heard it's very difficult to do

I believe this is the problem they have:
http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=13834

Comment: you mean the toolbar is horizontal and you want to use a vertical one instead?

Comment: I'm thinking he means for languages that write top to bottom first, like Japanese.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picking up on Karsten’s suggestion to amend TinyMCE’s layout so that it has a vertical toolbar, [Googling “wysiwyg editor vertical toolbar”](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=wysiwyg+editor+vertical+toolbar&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) turned up this page on the TinyMCE forums:

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=13834

Looks like you’re allowed to change TinyMCE, but that achieving the vertical toolbar involves doing a custom layout:

http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/theme_advanced_custom_layout

I think you’ll need someone with HTML, CSS and JavaScript skills for this. No idea how long it’d take. Someone might have already done it, but [Googling “tinymce "vertical toolbar"”](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=tinymce+%22vertical+toolbar%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) only turns up 9 results.

Answer (score 2):

If it is only the toolbar, you could try to move it (i.e. with tinymce) via css. I just overlooked the html code and i see a simple table construct there.

Comment: I thought it would be simple too, but my developers claim it will take months to do it :/ so I just don't know what the problem is

Comment: could you let us hear/see their explanation why and what would take them so long?

Comment: It depends what you asked your developers to do. If you asked them to build you a WYSIWYG editor like TinyMCE, but with a vertical toolbar, then that would take months, because building something like TinyMCE takes a long time.

Karsten’s suggested taking TinyMCE itself, and amending it. This isn’t trivial either: as your developers didn’t write TinyMCE, they can’t be sure how difficult it’d be to change it without breaking it. Aside from that, I’m not sure if TinyMCE’s licence allows you to take the code and amend it.

Comment: And it’s off-topic for the question, but it does sounds a bit like you’ve asked your developers for an estimate, you don’t like that it sounds too long, so now you’re asking us.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a text area widget:

```
<textarea wrap=true rows=10 cols=5>xxx</textarea>
```

This would create a "vertical" entry area.

Using the css overflow:hidden will remove the scrollbars entirely as well.